# redirect to previous page on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to redirect to the previous page once an item is edited but it's redirecting to the same page (edit) again.

I've tried with `Redirect::back()` and `URL:previous()`. This is the flow:

1. (init from one of this two pages) show_pageA or show_pageB
2. ->(user clicks edit button) itemcontroller@edit
3. ->(clicks save) itemcontroller@store
4. ->(store method ends redirecting back) itemcontroller@edit

Instead of being redirected at the steep 4 to itemcontroller@edit I'd like to be redirected to 1. No mather if the page was show_pageA or show_pageB **(so I can't do any redirect to *specific_page*)**. How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the same issue as with redirecting user after a Login - a lot of developers want to redirect to the page from where the user came to login page.

So, what you have to do, is to store the page in the session when you open the GET 'edit' URL and then use it to redirect the user.

Answer (score 1):

Technically what you can do in your itemcontroller@edit, get where the request came from, pass it as variable to @store method and then when save is clicked redirect back to that variable that was passed by @edit.